# I get very strange error while im trying to finish my project

Tags: python, random

This code is meant to pick an artist from internal file (text file), read it and pick randomly from the internal file the artist (that are in the text file in array style, e.g., "carrot apple banana"), therefore I added .txt to the chosen artist so the program will open artist's file with songs and pick a random song.

```
import random

loop = False
counter = 0
points = 0
max_level = 10
while loop == False:

   for lines in open("pick.txt").readlines():
          art = lines.split()
          artist = random.choice(art)

   for i in open((artist) + ".txt"):
          song = i.split()
          song_name = random.choice(song)

          print("the song begins with  :" , song_name , "this song is by :" , artist)
          answer = input("Enter full name of the song :  ")

   if answer == song_name:
          points = points +3
          print("correct")
          counter = counter +1
          print(counter)
   elif answer != song_name:
          print("WRONG !!! \n try again")
          dec = input("Please enter the full name of the song :")

          if dec == song_name:
                 points = points +2
                 print("correct")
                 counter = counter +1
                 print(counter)

          elif dec != song_name:
                 print("smh \n WRONG")
                 counter = counter +1
                 print(counter)

   elif counter >= max_level:
          print("The End")
          quit()

   else:
          print("error")

input()
```

Afterwards when I run the code in python shell, there is a random chance that I get this error, either straight away or later on:

```
raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. There's nothing strange about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is from the `random` module by the looks of it. This is probably when you’re reading the file and there is a line that is blank.

A cause is usually the last line of the file which is often a blank newline/EOF.

Just add a check when reading your file(s):

```
for line in open(artist + '.txt', 'r'):
    if line.strip():
        song = line.strip().split()
        song_name = random.choice(song)
```

An empty line will have a ‘truthiness’ value of 0 or `False` so a line with content returns`True`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error probably arises from an empty line in one of your text-files.

I was able to duplicate your error with your exact code and the following text-files:

pick.txt with only the word adele,
and adele.txt with hello-from-the-other-side and two new lines.

You can test this in prelude:

```
>>> for i in open("adele.txt"):
...     song = i.split()
...
>>> song
[]
```

On another note, you seem to be iterating throughout the lines in a textfile before you do anything with the data in the lines. That can't possibly make sense. I would advice you to add things in a list as you go, and then select from this list instead.